# Django Multiprocessing: How can I run multiple processes simultaneously

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using a multiprocessing module to perform a task that is very time-consuming. With a single request, it works fine. but I am unable to generate multiple processes simultaneously.
So How can I perform multiple requests at the same time when other is already running.

Comment: Have you looked into Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.